# Does Cognito error message support non-English language?

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, internationalization, amazon-cognito

I built a simple web app using [AWS amplify](https://aws.github.io/aws-amplify/). Its [authentication module](https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-js/media/authentication_guide.html) works great and I can easily use [Amazon Cognito](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/) as the authentication provider. Cognito seems very promising and I'd like to use it for my project.

One problem with this approach is that any Cognito auth error message is in English even though most users will be non-English speaker; for example, my users will not be happy when the AWS amplify auth module returns `user does not exist.` or `Username/client id combination not found.` on the screen.

Does Cognito error message support any non-English language?

Answer (score -1):

**Short answer**: no it doesn't. You should provide the error in the language of your choice. You could also use the internationalization capabilities of your framework.

**Longer Answer for the sake of architecture**: Why are you passing the error message from Cognito to the user? There are several separated concerns:

**1. Views:** Your views (pages) should show the login and the errors it receives (if any).

**2. Controller**: You controller is a middleman here. It gets the login form and pass it to the model, and get a `boolean` response from the model; and decides what to sends to the user. Controller **does not know** what is Cognito, or any other service. All it knows is your model to call.

**3. Model**: Your model is responsible for knowing Cognito, and carries on with the communication with the Cognito. Any exception you get from Cognito, could be store/logged here and then the model sends back a general response to the controller.

So to sum up, to follow a MVC model, and also apply clean code principles, you **must not** go back and from from `views <-> controller <-> models` while all the components know what Cognito is.

For internationalization, your web framework could support it. For example, Playframework [supports it](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaI18N).

Comment: "Why are you passing the error message from Cognito to the user?" because you as a developer don't have to know every possible error message from AWS Cognito login form and those errors contain critical information for the end-user of the application. The point of outsourcing login logic is to not think about every case scenario for it.

Comment: @Deykun end-user has nothing to do with Cognito. I might move to google cloud and the functionality of end user should not change.  Everything should be localized and the error should be matched and then given to the end-user. Why if I’m a Netflix user I should get an error from AWS? Yes you should take care of every possible error msg coming from the services you are using.

Comment: Currently, you cannot localize it in the normal way because you don't receive error code: too short, or too easy (and in which way). You are getting string which is not documented anywhere and it contains critical information which you cannot simply replace with "something is wrong", I wish you good luck preparing for localization then. It is easier to create your own signup than trying to hack that.

Comment: And if you are using proxy then congratulations you dealing with that problem in your code trying to understand what is wrong with your user input data to tell him in his native language. And I would like to point out that this librarly is used in the frontend applications for example React not on the backend.

Comment: "Why are you passing the error message from Cognito to the user", the information is available in the frontend either way. You could simply element inspect the application and read out this information. If you want to prevent the contents of the error to be known to the user then you have to turn on some settings on the AWS platform so that aws cognito will return a generic error.